# Reconnect to SMB share does not work after resume from sleep (Catalina, Synology NAS)

Tags: finder, catalina, nas

After "resume from sleep" my MacBook Pro can not reconnect to an SMB share on a Synology NAS Server.

> The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “XYZ”
>   can’t be found.

This only affects the Finder. The file open dialog in applications (e.g. Numbers) works perfectly (browsing the directory tree, open files etc.).

Restarting Finder, deleting the preference file for Finder, disconnecting/ reconnecting with "goto Server" does not change the error message when clicking on the XYZ directory in Finder.

As the OS was an update to Catalina I performed a clean install. Same problem.

Comment: Same here. Seems to be a bug in Catalina. DSM version has not changed, also no problems with the Bonjour announcement of the SMB serve from DSM. For me the sidebar share comes back after a restart of macOS. I made aliases for my shares and put them on the Desktop for now. I reported this as a bug via Radar, you should do the same.

Comment: Thank. I raised this issue with Apple. Lets hope for a fix as this is pretty annoying!

Comment: Not just Mac -> NAS. I get inconsistent Finder connections Mac -> Mac.  I use a script to create the connections.

Comment: @Camissa: Hi - it's now April 17, 2022. I'm posting this comment to ask if you ever got that fix from Apple you were hoping for. I haven't, and I've decided that Apple must be having some "issues" with `software quality`... the term seems to be an *oxymoron* at Apple.

Comment: @Gilby said, *" I use a script to create the connections."* If this works well for you, I'm sure there are many who'd like to know how you do this... hint, hint - the answer box below awaits you  :)